# What do we know about $\text{sgn}^T(x)Qx$?

Tags: matrices

Suppose $Q$ is symmetric and positive semi-definite, then what properties can we know from $\text{sgn}^T(x)Qx$? Especially, is there any relation between $\text{sgn}^T(x)Qx$? and $\text{sgn}^T(x) x$?

Clarify on the notation: $\text{sgn}(x)=1 ,x>0;\; \text{sgn}(x)=-1 ,x<0;\; \text{sgn}(x)=0 ,x=0$.

Comment: Can you clarify your notation here? I think that if $x = (3,0,-2)^T$, then I think that
$$
\operatorname{sgn}^T(x) = (1,0,-1)
$$
is this the correct interpretation?

Comment: Also: what kind of relation between the two might you be expecting?

Comment: It might be useful to observe that you can rewrite the expressions as
$$
\operatorname{sgn}^T(x) Q \operatorname{diag}(x) \operatorname{sgn}(x), \qquad 
\operatorname{sgn}^T(x) \operatorname{diag}(x) \operatorname{sgn}(x)
$$
respectively, where $\operatorname{diag}(x)$ is the diagonal matrix
$$
\operatorname{diag}(x) = \pmatrix{x_1 \\ & \ddots \\ && x_n}
$$

Comment: @Omnomnomnom Yes, you are right!

Comment: @Omnomnomnom About your third comment, you are incorrect.

Comment: Is $x = \operatorname{diag}(x) \operatorname{sgn}(x)$ incorrect?

Comment: Sorry! That should be $x = \operatorname{diag}(|x|) \operatorname{sgn}(x)$.